# Azure Pipelines (YAML) Job not running when using job type 'deployment'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Deployment job is not running at all. Returns a failed status without any error message.
Here's the test YAML pipeline:

```
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy_Test
    environment:
      name: 'DOKS-Production'
      resourceName: 'default'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo deploy stage ran
```

[image]

[image]

Oddly when I switch over to the following, it works fine.

```
jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - script: echo deploy stage ran
```

Comment: Do you have a resource in your environment named `default`? When you specify `resourceName`, it tries to run the provided steps on that resource.

Comment: Yes. I've got a Kubernetes Resource named default (due to namespace)

Comment: @DanielMann Hmm. Oddly I just ran this on another devops environment with the same environment and resource (same configuration), and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who had run into the same issue, I managed to get it working by simply creating a new environment in Azure DevOps. Seems like the existing environment was corrupt in someway.